# How to insert commas in a string after two words in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text document with name and address telephone numbers. 
Example 
Abdul Rashid a025684t@usa.nit 245 ST.CLOUD VILLAGi CT. # 101 MILPTTAS CA 73634 9600280136 US MALE Sunday, March 10,1957 175 195 B+  Abdul Rashid DELVAAJAQUE CAMPBELL CA 3924 US 8795672807 NO MO NO NO NO RnM-094_1898 Sunday, March 10, 1957 $200.00 Abdul Rashid EUGENE FANTER BaX_0laCm-4630 Sunday, March 10, 1957 MALE American Express XANAX 37.5 MG 60 $430 $258.00 $20.00 $278.00 Not Available.

I want to do something like this,
Abdul Rashid, z025684t@usa.nit, 245 st. cloud villagi ct. # 101, Milpttas, ca, 73634 so on.

Using notepad, I did try with code alignment, it did not get as I expected.

Comment: is the data formatted in any predictable structure? otherwise it might be difficult, e.g. a person with a middle name, addresses with multiple words etc

Answer (score 0):

Be awate of privacy and security issues: you are spreading on the web mr Rashid's personal data.
About your question there is no easy answer, you should have a fixed data structure, but it seems you haven't.
Maybe you should try to normalize your data.

Comment: This is dummy data so there is no problem with the security and private issues.